# Javascript - How to add a pause button in carousel?

Tags: php, javascript, magento, carousel

I have found this script in Magento which is rotating images from a certain directory. This is working fine. But I need to add a "pause" button after the "1-6". I am not an expert on javascript so not sure how to do this. Can someone please help me with this?

The code:

```
<?php
$speed = 5000;//miliseconds
?>


<script type="text/javascript">
var timeoutID;

homeTileCount = 1;
$$('.home-tile-container img').each(function(e){
    $(e).writeAttribute('id','home-tile-' + homeTileCount);
    $(e).addClassName('home-tile');
    homeTileCount++;
});

homeTileCount--;

var homeTileRemote = $$('.home-tile-remote')[0];
for (i=homeTileCount;i>=1;i--)
    homeTileRemote.insert('<div id="home-tile-remote-'+i+'" class="overflow"><a href="#" onclick="switchTile('+i+');return false">'+i+'</a></div>');

function switchTile(n)
{
    //console.log(n);
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    $$('.home-tile-container img').each(function(e){
        e.removeClassName('home-tile-active');
    });

    $$('.home-tile-remote > div').each(function(e){
        e.removeClassName('home-tile-remote-active');
    });

    $('home-tile-remote-'+n).addClassName('home-tile-remote-active');
    $('home-tile-'+n).addClassName('home-tile-active');
    next = n+1;
    if (next > homeTileCount)
        next = 1;
    timeoutID = setTimeout('switchTile('+next+')', <?=$speed?>);
}

switchTile(1);
setTimeout('switchTile(2)', <?=$speed?>);
</script>
```

And this is how the carousel looks:   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
<?php
$speed = 5000;//miliseconds
?>


<script type="text/javascript">
var paused=false;
var timeoutID;

homeTileCount = 1;
$$('.home-tile-container img').each(function(e){
$(e).writeAttribute('id','home-tile-' + homeTileCount);
$(e).addClassName('home-tile');
homeTileCount++;
});

homeTileCount--;

var homeTileRemote = $$('.home-tile-remote')[0];
for (i=homeTileCount;i>=1;i--)
    homeTileRemote.insert('<div id="home-tile-remote-'+i+'" class="overflow"><a href="#" onclick="switchTile('+i+');return false">'+i+'</a></div>');

function switchTile(n)
{
if (!paused) {
    //console.log(n);
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    $$('.home-tile-container img').each(function(e){
        e.removeClassName('home-tile-active');
    });

    $$('.home-tile-remote > div').each(function(e){
        e.removeClassName('home-tile-remote-active');
    });

    $('home-tile-remote-'+n).addClassName('home-tile-remote-active');
    $('home-tile-'+n).addClassName('home-tile-active');
    next = n+1;
    if (next > homeTileCount)
        next = 1;
    timeoutID = setTimeout('switchTile('+next+')', <?=$speed?>);
    }
    }

switchTile(1);
setTimeout('switchTile(2)', <?=$speed?>);
</script>
<button type="button" onclick="paused=true;">Pause</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That did the work. :) +1

Can you please help me with one other thing: if the button is pressed then the slide is paused which is perfect. But how can I make the button to resume play again? I mean sort of toggle? play/pause?

Comment: @meraz Change the last row to this: <button type="button" onclick="if (!paused){paused=true;}else{paused=false;}">Pause</button>

Comment: Thank you gskartwii. But it's not working. Pause is working correctly. But once paused clicking it again is not resuming the play. :/ Can you please help?

Please note: I have posted another question in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945612/javascript-play-pause-not-working-in-carousel So don't get surprised if you see the same question. Thank you.