# javascript: play/pause not working in carousel?

Tags: php, javascript, carousel

I have got a script which runs a carousel in the site. This is the script which is doing the work. And I need to add a play/pause button in there. User @gskartwii has helped me in here [Javascript - How to add a pause button in carousel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12927829/javascript-how-to-add-a-pause-button-in-carousel/12928315#comment17536757_12928315) to add the button. And I have modified the code to adjust with the design.

The problem is pause is working fine. But once it's paused clicking it again is not resuming the play! I am not an expert on Javascript, so not sure what should I need to cahnge. :/

Can someone please help me on this.

And this is the script:

```
 <?php
$speed = 500;//miliseconds
?>


<script type="text/javascript">
var paused=false;
var timeoutID;

homeTileCount = 1;
$$('.home-tile-container img').each(function(e){
    $(e).writeAttribute('id','home-tile-' + homeTileCount);
    $(e).addClassName('home-tile');
    homeTileCount++;
});

homeTileCount--;

var homeTileRemote = $$('.home-tile-remote')[0];

//play / pause button start
homeTileRemote.insert('<div id="home-title-remote-10" class="overflow"><a href="#" onclick="if(!paused){paused=true} else{paused=false}">| |</a></div>');
//play/pause button end

for (i=homeTileCount;i>=1;i--){
    homeTileRemote.insert('<div id="home-tile-remote-'+i+'" class="overflow"><a href="#" onclick="switchTile('+i+');return false">'+i+'</a></div>');
}

function switchTile(n)
{
    if(!paused){
    //console.log(n);
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    $$('.home-tile-container img').each(function(e){
        e.removeClassName('home-tile-active');
    });

    $$('.home-tile-remote > div').each(function(e){
        e.removeClassName('home-tile-remote-active');
    });

    $('home-tile-remote-'+n).addClassName('home-tile-remote-active');
    $('home-tile-'+n).addClassName('home-tile-active');
    next = n+1;
    if (next > homeTileCount)
        next = 1;
    timeoutID = setTimeout('switchTile('+next+')', <?=$speed?>);}
}

switchTile(1);
setTimeout('switchTile(2)', <?=$speed?>);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Referencing from other question you asked, if you have a button:

`<button type="button" onclick="paused=true;">Pause</button>`

then play button should be

`<button type="button" onclick="paused=false;">Play</button>`